# Unable to install PHP GD on version 7.2 UBUNTU

Tags: php

When I try to install it with `sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd`
But i get this error

```
Depends: libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

I try to fix it and install libjpeg62-turbo

```
E: Package 'libjpeg62-turbo' has no installation candidate
```

The result is Package 'libjpeg62-turbo' has no installation candidate

Comment: Did you try apt-get update? Are you using ondres ppa?

Comment: i try it  , yes I use ondrejppa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Here is the fix**

Download the old version of libjpeg62-turbo

```
 wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.2-2+b1_amd64.deb
```

Run the below commands

```
 sudo dpkg -i libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.2-2+b1_amd64.deb

 apt-get install php7.2-gd
```

and then restart phpfpm

Comment: wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.2-2+b1_amd64.de

not found

Comment: try: http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg62-turbo_2.0.6-4_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

Could you try installing `libjpeg62-dev`?

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libjpeg&searchon=names